# WSO2 ESB - how to unwrap the SOAP envelope of REST messagess

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I noticed that REST messages are wrapped in a SOAP envelope by the ESB. Is there a way to keep the message as POX even inside the ESB, without being wrapped by a SOAP envelope? I tried setting `format="rest"` by using an http endpoint. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Within the ESB, message get converted to a soap message regardless of incoming/out going message format. That is happening to provide a consistent message format to all the mediators to work with. What you can do is, remove the soap envelope when message is going out from the ESB by setting the format="pox".